# Handshake error sporadically occuring -using tyrus client android

Tags: android, ssl, websocket, grizzly, tyrus

The following issue occurs sporadically..
I have seen some posts like 
[Websocket SSL handshake failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28011581/websocket-ssl-handshake-failure)
Please dont mark this question as duplicate unless there is concrete answer.I couldnt get a work around what exactly needs to be done for tyrus client Or which library supports the usage of SSL on android...

## Following is the exception:

```
javax.websocket.DeploymentException: SSL handshake has failed
05-09 20:16:00.850 23627-23784/ W/System.err:     at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientSocket._connect(GrizzlyClientSocket.java:396)
05-09 20:16:00.851 23627-23784/ W/System.err:     at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientSocket.access$000(GrizzlyClientSocket.java:103)
05-09 20:16:00.851 23627-23784/ W/System.err:     at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientSocket$1.call(GrizzlyClientSocket.java:235)
05-09 20:16:00.851 23627-23784/ W/System.err:     at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientSocket$1.call(GrizzlyClientSocket.java:231)
05-09 20:16:00.851 23627-23784/ W/System.err:     at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientSocket.connect(GrizzlyClientSocket.java:249)
05-09 20:16:00.851 23627-23784/ W/System.err:     at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientContainer.openClientSocket(GrizzlyClientContainer.java:95)
05-09 20:16:00.851 23627-23784/ W/System.err:     at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$3$1.run(ClientManager.java:663)
05-09 20:16:00.851 23627-23784/ W/System.err:     at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$3.run(ClientManager.java:712)
05-09 20:16:00.851 23627-23784/ W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
05-09 20:16:00.851 23627-23784/ W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
05-09 20:16:00.851 23627-23784/ W/System.err:     at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(ClientManager.java:866)
05-09 20:16:00.851 23627-23784/ W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:82)
05-09 20:16:00.851 23627-23784/ W/System.err:     at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.connectToServer(ClientManager.java:511)
05-09 20:16:00.851 23627-23784/ W/System.err:     at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.connectToServer(ClientManager.java:373)
```

Comment: please share Tyrus version you are  using..

Comment: It's worth trying [nv-websocket-client](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client).

Comment: @TakahikoKawasaki..Thanks a lot..have implemented using nv-websocket-client ..Documentation was also very helpful..

Comment: @PavelBucek..I am using 1.12 version of tyrus client